# Sporadic Unknown error (0x8005000) when connecting with LDAP

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I am encountering a sporadic error with the codebase I'm working on, which manifests as an "Unknown Error (0x80005000)". The issue seems to happen only sometimes (once or twice a week), and the current workaround is to restart the site, which is not a sustainable solution. I'm looking to identify the root cause and find a permanent resolution.

Error:

```
    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: Unknown error (0x80005000)
---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unknown error (0x80005000)   
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)   
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()    
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()    
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()    
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)    
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)    
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.IsContainer(DirectoryEntry de)    
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx..ctor(DirectoryEntry ctxBase, Boolean ownCtxBase, String username, String password, ContextOptions options)    
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.CreateContextFromDirectoryEntry(DirectoryEntry entry)    
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit()    
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit()    
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()    
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()    
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_ConnectedServer()
```

Did some research and found following

- Might be related to high workload of authentication server. But there seems to be no sign of high Usage.
- incorrect url. I checked the URL, it uses LDAP://
- Might occur when accessing invalid attribute. Questioning this, since it works most of the time with the same error. Only errors sometimes (once/twice a week)